# Discrete coloring in Plots

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to have a plot that is filled to the axis with `Green` if the `y` value is greater than 10, and `Blue` if it is less than 10.

I attempted to do the following:

`Plot[x, {x, 0, 20}, Filling -> Axis, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, Piecewise[{{Green, y > 10}, {Blue, y < 10}}]]]`

The produces an all blue filling.

The frustrating thing is that it seems that conditionals are allowed in `ColorFunction`s, but the test is evaluated only once, and the result is evaluation for each point plotted.

How can I have the test evaluated repeatedly to get a discrete color filling?

**Note:** I am simply trying to fill the space under a curve by determining where a point would fall in a given set of intervals.

Comment: Incidentally your code can be simplified: `ColorFunction -> (If[#2 > 10, Green, Blue] &)`

Comment: In the code that I am actually using, there are 5 intervals, so I just removed some, and changed the numbers for the piecewise function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ParametricPlot` with `MeshFunctions` + `MeshShading` +`Mesh` options gives a cleaner picture with no blending of colors at boundaries:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, v x}, {x, 0, 20}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# &}, Mesh -> {{10}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Blue, Green}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

You can color more complicated regions:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, v x}, {x, 0, 20}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# Sin[RandomReal[5] + #] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Hue[RandomReal[]], Hue[RandomReal[]]}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

The problem is not that the test is only evaluated once but that by default `ColorFunctionScaling` is set to `True` which means that the coordinates are rescaled to lie in the interval $[0,1]$ before being fed to `ColorFunction`. Try this instead

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 20}, Filling -> Axis, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Piecewise[{{Green, y > 10}, {Blue, y < 10}}]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]