# Generating stripes on a polygon

Tags: graphics3d

I want to create a `Graphics3D` polygon that has stripes on it. My code is

```
 Graphics3D[{
   LightBlue, 
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]}, 
   Boxed -> False,
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}},
   ViewPoint -> {0.2, 0, 0.2}, 
   RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

I want horizontal equidistant stripes on it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have a look at [Texture](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html?q=Texture&lang=en). This might be what you need.

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3723/5

Comment: Also related: [(6741)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6741/121)

Answer (score 9):

I commented out some of the options, because they made it difficult for me to see what was exactly happening. [*Edit*: Change the texture pattern to a variable, to clarify how to modify it.  A line pattern given at end.]

```
stripePattern = 
  Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1/2}], Blue, 
    Rectangle[{0, 1/2}, {1, 1}]}, PlotRangePadding -> 0];

Graphics3D[{Texture[stripePattern], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 4}, {0, 4}}]}, 
 Boxed -> False
 (*,Lighting->{{"Ambient",LightBlue}},ViewPoint->{0.2,0,0.2},RotationAction->"Clip"*)
]
```

[image: Striped rectangle]

If you have arbitrary polygons, then I don't know how to make the computation of `VertexTextureCoordinates` *easily* automatic.  (One could compute a projection rather automatically I suppose.)  @Mr.Wizard's answer might be easiest in that case.

```
Graphics3D[{Texture[stripePattern], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 2}, {0, 3, 1}, {0, 2, 0}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 4}, {1/2, 6}, {0, 4}}]}, 
 Boxed -> False
]
```

[image: Striped pentagon]

**Addendum - Edited**

Here's a projection function that projects the polygon onto the texture coordinate system.  (Please excuse not putting in full error checking.)

I have edited the code to replace the pattern by lines instead of stripes, per the OP's query.

```
project[polygonVertices_, stripeDirection_, nStripeMultiplier_] := 
  Module[{normal, e1, e2},
    normal = 
     Normalize@
      Catch[(If[Chop[#] != {0, 0, 0}, Throw[#]] &@(Cross @@ Differences[#])) & /@ 
         Partition[polygonVertices, 3, 1, 1];];
    e2 = normal\[Cross]Normalize[stripeDirection];
    e1 = e2\[Cross]normal;
    polygonVertices.Transpose[{e1, nStripeMultiplier e2}]
    ] /; Length[polygonVertices] >= 3;

linePattern = 
  Graphics[{Thickness[0.15], Red, Line[{{0, 1/2}, {1, 1/2}}]}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];

With[{poly = 
   Table[RandomReal[{1, 2}] {Cos[t], Sin[t], 
      Cos[t] - 2 Sin[t]}, {t, π/6, 2 π, π/6}]}, 
 Graphics3D[{Texture[linePattern], 
   Polygon[poly, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> project[poly, {-2, -2, 2}, 4]]}, 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
 ]
```

[image: Striped polygon]

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Instead of Stripes ,how can i change it to lines  on my polygon.?

Comment: @santhosh.L See edits.  The graphic in `Texture[..]` can be replaced by any `Graphics` or `Image`.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can parametrize your polygon and use `ParametricPlot3D` which takes `MeshFunctions` / `MeshShading` options.  Alternately you could try interpolating your data and using `ListSurfacePlot3D` which also takes these options.

An example from the `MeshFunctions` documentation (using `Plot3D`):

```
Plot3D[
 (x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 25,
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 MeshStyle -> Purple, 
 MeshShading -> {None, Green, None, Yellow}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another from the `ParametricPlot3D` documentation:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  {(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], Sin[v]},
  {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  Mesh -> 15,
  MeshShading -> {Red, Blue},
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And finally one for `ListSurfacePlot3D`

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> 30, Axes -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> (#1 - #2 + #3 &), MeshShading -> {None, Yellow}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Using improved `Texture` capability in v14:

```
p1 = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[18], 
   Table[{If[EvenQ[Floor@(10 k/2)], Red, Blue], 
     Line[{{k, -1}, {k + 1, 1}}]}, {k, -2, 2, .2}]}, PlotRange -> 1];

Graphics3D[{Texture[p1], Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]}]
```

### [image]

Using @MichaelE2's example:

```
With[{poly = 
   Table[RandomReal[{1, 2}] {Cos[t], Sin[t], 
      Cos[t] - 2 Sin[t]}, {t, \[Pi]/6, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/6}]}, 
 Graphics3D[{Texture[p1], 
   Polygon[poly]}, 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1)  I dot know why 13.3.1  doesn't work and only  14.0 work. What is the updated of 14.0?

Comment: I was reading the release [announcement](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2024/01/the-story-continues-announcing-version-14-of-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/) so decided to try on the cloud. I cannot say since I have 12.2.0.