# Two discrete colors for surface with ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to create a plot of a surface that is yellow above the xy-plane (z>0), but blue below (z<0). My first attempt was to use `ColorFunction->Function[{x,y,z},If[z>0,Hue[0.2],Hue[0.6]]`, but this only gave me a solid yellow paraboloid. I also tried defining a custom ColorFunction scheme with `cf=Piecewise[{{Yellow,0<#3<30},{Blue,-70<#3<0}}]&;` and `ColorFunction->cf` to the same result. Finally, I tried the following based on another thread ([Discrete coloring in Plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/discrete-coloring-in-plots)):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x,y,x^2+y^2-5},{y,-3,3},{x,-3,3},PlotStyle->Opacity[.8],ColorFunction->(If[#3>0,Yellow,Blue]&),Mesh->False,BoundaryStyle->{Black,Thickness[.01]}]
```

Every time, I end up with this:

[image: yellow paraboloid]

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`? and a large value for `PlotPoints` , e.g., `PlotPoints -> 150`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to limit the artifacts near z=0 so that it is more of a discrete color change? `PlotPoints->100` works, but it slows everything down.

http://i.imgur.com/tFh63XY.jpg

Comment: Worf, i don't know of any way to get rid of the jagged ring. A work-around is to "hide" it under a  mesh at 0 using the combination  of options `MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[.8], Thickness[.01]]`. ... Just learned myself the best way: Michael's approach using `MeshShading` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `MeshShading`, as shown in the documentation for [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, x^2 + y^2 - 5}, {y, -3, 3}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 MeshShading -> {Directive[Opacity[.8], Blue], 
   Directive[Opacity[.8], Yellow]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thickness[.01]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use your `cf` as the setting for `ColorFunction` and add the option
   `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.
2. To get a sharp change from `Blue` to `Yellow` add the options `Exclusions -> {x^2 + y^2 == 5}` and `ExclusionsStyle -> Blue`.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, x^2 + y^2 - 5}, {y, -3, 3}, {x, -3, 3},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8], Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thickness[.01]},
 ColorFunction -> cf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 Exclusions -> {x^2 + y^2 == 5}, ExclusionsStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]