# Piecewise ColorFunction fails

Tags: plotting, color

I have *Mathematica* 10.3, and when I run

```
MyColorFunc[z_] := Piecewise[{{Blue, z > 0}, {Green, z == 0}, {Red, z < 0}}];
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 3;
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> MyColorFunc, 
       PlotRange -> All]
```

the entirety of the plot is blue, apart from a spot where it's green (at 0,0 where it should really be blue).

Is this a bug in my version, or I am doing something wrong? I have similar issues with `ContourPlot`.

Comment: Related, perhaps a duplicate: [(55278)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55278/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Green]}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[ConditionalExpression[f[x, y], #] & /@ {f[x, y] <= 0, 
    f[x, y] > 0}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> Directive[Thick, Green], 2 -> None}]
```

[image]

Compare with what you get with `ColorFunction` (note the absence of `Green` line and the blending of `Red` and `Blue` at the boundary):

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> MyColorFunc, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

**Update:** We can eliminate the blending using `Exclusions -> {f[x,y] == 0}` and  use the option `ExclusionsStyle` to color the boundary between the two pieces:

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Exclusions -> {f[x, y] == 0}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Thick, Green], 
 ColorFunction -> MyColorFunc, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, thanks,

Comment: @ThreeDiag, my pleasure.

Answer (score 7):

With `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` (the default), 1D color functions are scaled to the domain `[0,1]`. `cf[z_] := Piecewise[{{Blue, z > 1/2}, {Green, z == 1/2}, {Red, z < 1/2}}]` colors the lower half red and the upper half blue.

With `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, the actual `z` value is used instead, allowing the original function to work (likely as you intended).

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I've stumbled upon a similar post a Second before you answered, so my q is likely a duplicate, but thanks =)

Comment: @ThreeDiag If it is a duplicate or another question helped you out, it'd be good to link the other question so that other people can find it more easily. Even if this question ends up getting closed, there's no harm in having the additional information available.

Answer (score 2):

Define the function with `MyColorFunc[args__]`.

Try using `ColorFunction -> (MyColorFunc[##]&)`.

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html), the arguments are scaled versions of the $x$, $y$ and $z$  coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've already gotten some great answers that touch upon the importance of `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, let me just demonstrate another method for the kind of coloring you want to do:

```
myColorFunction = Blend[{ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", "Reverse"},
                                   LogisticSigmoid[80 #]],
                         Green}, Exp[-80 #^2]] &;
```

where we use a sigmoid to map $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$ for `ColorData[]`, and use a sharply peaked Gaussian along with `Blend[]` to insert the green color at $0$. With this,

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2 - 3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
       ColorFunction -> (myColorFunction[#3] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
       Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 105, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: three-color surface]